# Should we request an arXiv trackbacks feature?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined

Question inspired by Kaveh, one of the cstheory mods, [here on cstheory Meta](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/arxiv-trackbacks), which in turn was inspired by [this post on Theoretical Physics Meta](http://meta.theoreticalphysics.stackexchange.com/questions/227/arxiv-trackbacks-working).

As I understand it, this feature would enable people who look at articles on the arXiv to see if they've been mentioned on scicomp. There haven't been any links to articles on the arXiv from scicomp questions so far, to my knowledge. As a reader of math.NA on arXiv, I know it'd be of some interest to me, at least, and maybe others.

Comment: [Related question on SE mother meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240520/209806).

Comment: [Feature implementation discussion:](https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/q/544/20688)

Comment: Moving this to status-declined. Its been submitted internally to be considered for implementation, but for the time being, it's gonna be a no.

Answer (score 4):

Yes!   This is also a great way to get a bit more traffic here too :)