# arXiv trackbacks from Computational Science SE - are possible!

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined

A very long time ago, [a feature for providing arXiv trackbacks](https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/q/192/20688) has been requested.

There is also a highly upvoted [Meta StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240520/383809) discussion, requesting the same functionality. Unfortunately, it seems like we are quite far from getting an official implementation of this highly impactful feature for a small subset of communities.

However, [MathOverflow has their custom implementation and they are very willing to share!](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/4255/121862) Thanks, [ScottMorrison](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/users/3/scott-morrison).

Now, I have the code for the script, and we have two options:

**Option 1:**

**Run a slightly modified script on our server.**

By our server, I mean not SE, but, say, a personal server of one of the highly-active members of the community. I have access to set up this script on one of the servers available to me.

- We have the ability to control this script and, possibly, fix things independently from MathOverflow (still, I would probably go for some joint GitHub repository or so, provided the permission is granted).
- We would have to arrange our own whitelisting with arXiv

**Option 2**:

**Augment the provided script, and run it together with MathOverflow on their private server.**

- Less maintenance
- I should be more careful modifying the script (as being "poked" by one community is a routine, while being "yelled" by two is certainly a party)

Soon, I am going to go over the code and see how much work should I do in development\testing\deployment. I welcome the opinions on this feature, implementation, scenarios, possible drawbacks, etc.

Comment: Excellent, thanks a lot for pursuing this! I believe option 2 would be preferable as far as possible; the main question is to identify if and what would be possible/desirable to change. I can't think of anything, except possibly the arXiv categories -- are these currently restricted?

Comment: And the more code on github/gitlab/whatever, the better!

Comment: Moving this to status-declined. It has been submitted internally to be considered for implementation, but it will be a no for the time being.